# How to check if a text box is not empty and the value is less than 500

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a textbox that is an optional field for users to enter a number in to.  If there is a number in there, I want to check to make sure it is less than 500 and then do something with it.

Here is what I am currently doing:

```
if($textbox!="" && <=500)
{
//action here
}
```

I tried replacing && with andif but still get an error **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IS_SMALLER_OR_EQUAL**

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the variable in both statements
preg_match('/\d/', $textbox ) == 1 will make sure it's an int

```
if($textbox!="" && $textbox <= 500 && preg_match('/\d/', $textbox ) == 1)
{
//action here
}
```

Comment: Bringing regex into this is overkill.  Personally, I'd recommend going with: `if (!empty($textbox) && intval($textbox) <= 500) { /* CODE */ }`

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that I forgot to put an `is_numeric` in there but it was already too late to edit.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the left part of the lesser than

```
if($textbox!="" && $textbox <=500)
{
//action here
}
```